# Golang file and folder replication / mirroring across multiple servers

Tags: go

Consider this scenario. In a load-balanced environment, I have 3 separate instances of a CMS running on 3 different physical servers. These 3 separate running instances of the application is sharing the same database.

On each server, the CMS has a /media folder where all media subfolders and files reside. My question is how I'd implement/code a file replication service/functionality in Golang, so when a subfolder or file is added/changed/deleted on one of the servers, it'll get copied/replicated/deleted on all other servers?

What packages would I need to look in to, or perhaps you have a small code snippet to help me get started? That would be awesome.

*Edit:
This question has been marked as "duplicate", but it is not. It is however an alternative to setting up a shared network file system. I'm thinking that keeping a copy of the same file on all servers, synchronizing and keeping them updated might be better than sharing them.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Network file share possible in Go load-balanced environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217922/network-file-share-possible-in-go-load-balanced-environment)

Comment: nope, this is the alternative approach im thinking might be a better alternative.

Comment: Even if it's not an exact duplicate, it still off topic, and not really programming related (unless you have a specific question about programming a file replication service, in which case, ask that question). Just like your other question, you should probably ask this on ServerFault or SuperUser.

Comment: Well it is a programming question since I need to implement this functionality in my application written in golang. What I'm asking is how I'd program such a thing in Go? But to make it clear i replaced the word "setup" with "implement/code". So What I'm asking is what libraries or perhaps a small code snippet to get me started or pointed in the right direction, if there should still be any doubt about the relevancy or what I'm asking.

Comment: See ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically #4 and its link. As for an example of how to do it yourself, a "file replication service" isn't something you can demonstrate in a small code snippet.

Comment: JimB, obviously you do not like or respect my question. If you do not have any constructive comments to lead me closer to an answer, can you at least stop commenting? This is a programming question, and one problem that I need to solve. I think it's a fair question, although certainly not easy. Asking for code snippets to point me in the right direction is certainly not forbidden by any law. There's not any info on how to achieve this in go, as far as I can tell by searching the web.

Comment: There already is a distributed replication program written in Go. It's called Syncthing.

Comment: Thanks andy. I'll check it out right now. See thats a comment I can use!

Comment: It's a valid question, and I'm just trying to get you to an answer. But being off topic here is just going to get closed or voted down. Setting up networked filesystems and file replication aren't uncommon tasks, but you're more likely to get an answer via ServerFault (or even SuperUser), since that is a common server administration task. As for your problem, it's even *more* common to share your assets outside of the filesystem, on a separate file server, or service like S3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't do this. Use a distributed file system, object storage (ala S3 or GCS) or a syncing program like btsync or syncthing.

If you still want to do this yourself, it will be challenging. You are basically building a distributed database and they are difficult to get right.

At first blush you could checkout something like [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) or [raft](https://github.com/hashicorp/raft), but unfortunately etcd doesn't work well with large files.

You could, on upload, also copy the file to every other server using [ssh](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh). But then what happens when a server goes down? Or what happens when two people update the same file at the same time?

Maybe you could design it such that every file gets a unique id (perhaps based on the hash of its contents so you can safely dedupe) and those files can never be updated or deleted, only added. That would solve the simultaneous update problem, but you'd still have the downtime problem.

One approach would be for each server to maintain an append-only version log when a file is added:

```
VERSION | FILE HASH
      1 |   abcd123
      2 |   efgh456
      3 |   ijkl789
```

With that you can pull every file from a server and a single number would be sufficient to know when a file is added. (For example if you think Server A is on version 5, and you get informed it is now on version 7, you know you need to sync 2 files)

You could do this with a database table:

```
ID | LOCAL_SERVER_ID | REMOTE_SERVER_ID | VERSION | FILE HASH
```

Which you could periodically poll and do your syncing via ssh or http between machines. If a server was down you could just retry until it works.

Or if you didn't want to have a centralized database for this you could use a library like [memberlist](https://godoc.org/github.com/hashicorp/memberlist). The local meta data for each node could be its version.

Either way there will be some amount of delay between a file was uploaded to a single server, and when it's available on all of them. Handling that well is hard, which is why you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do something similair to umbraco courier 2, but in the end I think perhaps I should start focussing on the application itself, without thinking too much about multi-site/load balancing networked setups. It looks like the external service, Syncthing would be able to keep files syncronized in a master/slave setup, and in PostgreSQL I guess master-slave database replication would be a viable solution. As the CMS progress however, I'd really like to build this functionality into the application itself, but I guess for now I'll do it like this, to lower complexity a bit.